# Install door trim where the door frame isn't exactly parallel to the drywall

Tags: drywall, doors, trim

I have an interior door where for whatever reason, the surface of the drywall isn't exactly parallel to the surface of the door frame.  If I put the trim on the drywall, the trim and the door frame meet at the top, but there's a gap (probably 1/8" or so) at the bottom. I could leave the gap, but it would look ugly.  I could put spackle in the gap, but it would look ugly and probably fall out over time.  How do I put the trim on so that there's no gap?

Comment: Proper way is to figure if door frame or wall is out of plumb and adjust.  Usually want door frame plumb if nothing else.  If door is working right(part way open it stays in place,no gaps at door stops), easy way is to use a wood shim to match difference of spacing.  Wood trim just might bend enough to hide 1/8 difference, if thin.

Comment: I measured, and the door is out of plumb (although it works fine.)  The "wood" (it's actually an engineered wood 1x4) won't bend, so shimming won't work either.  I thought about a long filler, but ripping a piece of wood that long and that thin is an exercise of frustration (or worse.)  I could take the door our and plumb it, but that seems like a lot of work for this project.

Comment: Should not be that much work really.  Pop off the door stop in the centre and can then remove that side, move so it matches the wall.  Most doors only attached to wall with a few nails and use the door stops to hide them.

Answer (score 2):

Decorator's caulk. Masks a myriad sins.

[Try living in an old Victorian house & be glad the top of the doorframe isn't itself at 10° off square ;) The doors here are mainly parallelograms.

Comment: Yes agreed, use paintable caulk (acrylic based with or without silicone) not spackle. 1/8in is really nothing to worry about.

Comment: That's good idea.  I also live in an old house where nothing is plumb, level, square or evenly spaced.  The door in question though is in an outbuilding which is modern.